# How to set a write rule based on value in firebase realtime database to a child node using auto generated push keys without authentication?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to set the write rule condition based on the value for each auto generated push key.

This is the realtime database json:

```js
{
  "child-node":  { 
    "-MySP3ncK324234pz_XZ": "test1",       
    "-MySP7ncK4545xEpz_AW": "test2",       
    "-MySddncKYwSxxEpzFRA": "test3"  
  }
}
```

If I set the below rule the write fails while using the rules playground:

```js
{
  "rules": { 
    "child-node": {          
      ".read": true,     
      ".write": true,    
      ".validate": "!newData.hasChild('child-node') && newData.val().contains('3')",      
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the write you perform in the playground, and the result you get from that?

Comment: Hi, sure, I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Accounts` in your screenshot is a composite node (an object with properties), its value is also an object and not a string value.

If you want to validate that `key` of the new data has value `"0"` that's be:

```
".validate": "newData.child('key').val() === '3'",
```

Or (a bit more readable imo):

```
"Accounts": {
  ...
  ".validate": "newData.hasChild('key')"
  "key": {
    ".validate": "newData.val() === '3'"
  }
  ...
}
```

There is no way in security rules to search across all child properties of a node, as that wouldn't scale. You will always have to be able to explicitly name the property you want to check the value of.

Comment: In my case the 'key' is the uid hash (as the json provided). Is there a way I know that value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you want to use the UID of the current user in the rules, that'd be `auth.uid`.

Comment: I am not using authentication,   "-MySP3ncK324234pz_XZ": "test1",  that starting hash is a automatically generated node key ? Is it possible to associate it with a value?

Comment: That's a so-called push key, as it's generated by the `push()` method of the Firebase SDKs. If your client knows the push key, they can pass that in to the database call (as part of the path they read/write or as part of the value they write), and the security rules can access it there. --- I have a feeling I'm missing something about your use-case and that we're looking at a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you edit your question to show what you are *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: The client doesn't know the push key (it's only sending the value: mRef.push().setValue("value");), the hash key it's auto-generated by firebase when a new line is written in the database. I am trying to set a rule that prevents unwanted future insertions from unknown users since the database is writeable by anybody. The solution was to make a regex on the value in order to prevent dummy insertions but I see that I'm stuck in this key problem. Thank you Frank for your helpful answers.

Comment: Too many words, not enough code - and it still seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables?